# reading entries from database through a drop down list

Tags: php, html, mysqli

how can i set it that the section drop down list shows all sections available for a certain subject, depending on the previous drop down list that contains subjects. For example: if i chose the subject A , it should show me all sections of subject A available. Currently the drop down of the subject works, it fetches all subjects available but im unable to make the second drop down fetch the sections since i want to make such that:

```
select section from class WHERE (name of subject chosen above is equal to the name column in the database.
```

Please ignore my code style since im a beginner after all. Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
<div>
            <label for="subjects" accesskey="o">Subject</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'afhfhdfhf', 'fhfhhfhfhfhf', 'fhfhfhfh') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = $conn->query("select name from class");

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='subject'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $name = $row['name']; 
                  echo '<option value="subject">'.$name.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
?> 
        </div>
<br>    
        <div>
            <label for="section" accesskey="o">Section</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'fgfgfgfg', 'rfgfgfgfg!~fgfgf', 'fgfgfgf') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = $conn->query("select section from class WHERE name = '$name'");

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $name = $row['name']; 
                  echo '<option value="">'.$name.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
?> 
        </div>
<br>
```

Comment: sidenote: you don't need to connect twice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- agreed, just connect at the top and use the same `$conn` variable for the 2nd query as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(n.b. this really should have been a comment, but it was too long for that, so answer it is :-)

You've got a few problems there... first, you are echoing out `<html>` and `<body>` tags, you already have those on the page, so you don't need to do that.

The second problem is that `$name` doesn't really exist in the way you are looking in the second query. In fact, it'll be the value of the last name you echo'd out in the first loop.

So, the fundamental issue is that PHP runs on the server and then is passed to the client and you want to limit a `select` based on user input that happens in the browser. So what you need to do is either on selection of the `subject`, submit back to the server to get the `section` OR you could use something like `jQuery` to do an `AJAX` call back to the server to retrieve this info (either as `JSON` that you can parse and use, or as `HTML` that you can plop into the form). 2nd option is definitely the way to go.

Have a google about this kinda thing and you'll find LOADS of examples and come on back here if you hit a road block :-)

Comment: if i wanted to do it php wise as in choose submit back to the server and get the section, would you guide me through it more?

Comment: @Sam that's not really how Stackoverflow is supposed to work, but I suppose I can help out a bit. Do you use GitHub or something like that?

Comment: i know stackoverflow isnt like that but i just need guiding.

Comment: Ok, against my better judgement... I'll drop a quick example on GitHub and post the link

Comment: EXTREMELY simple example https://github.com/knagurski/stackoverflow-select-example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76731/discussion-between-kevin-nagurski-and-sam).

Comment: Glad to be of help. Make sure you mark this as your chosen answer :-)